# HDD Missing After Installing Linux!

Tags: kali-linux, hard-disk, grub

I have 2 Hard Disks

**- C:/ (System)**

**- D:/ (Storage)**

I was trying to install Kali Linux using my USB, I downloaded the iso and burned it using unetbootin, I rebooted but it was not detecting the USB, I went to the BIOS settings, and changed my boot config from **UEFI** to **Legacy**, I saved the changes and rebooted, I was sent immediately to the Kali Linux GUI, tried to install it and I came to the step where it asked for a drive to install the GRUB on and it recommended to make it "**Guided - use entire disk**" because it did not detect any other OS probably because I changed the boot settings to Legacy, anyway I chose my D:/ drive because it had more space and the C:/ was used by Windows Already, after the installation process completed, it rebooted to a black screen with a blinking cursor on the top left.

I went back to the BIOS settings and changed the boot type from **Legacy** to **UEFI** and it booted to windows normally, but my D:/ drive is now missing!

*Now I can't boot into Kali Linux, and when I boot to windows (**D:/**) HDD is **missing***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If The Linux Distribution got installed on that D:/ Disk then it probably uses GPT as partition-table and has the ext (probably ext3 or ext4) filesystem on it. Windows can't read those (Linux can read almost all Filesystems there are, and definitely every common one including the windows ones NTFS and FAT)

How to make Windows read that Filesystems. 
That is a different question. I can not give you a full explanation of (but it should be pretty easy. Like install one driver or programm and it works).

I found this Tool: [Link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/)

> Ext2Read is an explorer like utility to explore ext2/ext3/ext4 files. It now supports LVM2 and EXT4 extents. It can be used to view and copy files and folders. It can recursively copy entire folders. It can also be used to view and copy disk and file.

I hope this was helpfull.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is there's any way to revert this? And restore the filesystem as it was before without losing data?

Comment: I don't know about your installation. But if you did a disk wide partition than the old partition containing the old filesystem got wiped. (Obviously) And I think this is the case becaaaaause: If you had made a separate partition for the os installation then the remaining windows one would still show you its filesystem (ntfs or fat) in the explorer. You could try some data recovery tools. That's all there is left sorry :/ But what the hell is Kali Linux dude.. as a beginner try something easy! Like, Ubuntu. I myself use Debian and I can barely use it!

Comment: I'm using my windows normally now installed on my C:/ drive but as I mentioned D:/ is missing, and I can't boot to Linux after changing from UEFI to Legacy it shows a black screen with a blinking cursor on the top left.

Comment: as I mentioned: the Disk does not get shown because windows can't read the filesystem you need to install something to give windows the ability to. About the files that were there I am pretty sure you can save them. If you find the right recovery tool. The partition containing the filesystem(what contains all files) got reformatted I am sure it wasn't a complete reformat where everything gets overwritten by zeros.

Comment: just the entries inside the partition table that mark where the partition starts and where it ends got rewritten. Then the space where the Linux files from the os installation got placed got overwritten. that is not a really big program Linux is usually never then a few gigs big.
so you need to find a recovery tool for recovering overwritten windows partitions.

Comment: Hmm, if this is the case, I have an external hard drive, I can boot into linux and copy my important data then format. But the problem is that I can't boot into linux because of the problem ... when booting to Linux I see a black screen with blinking cursor on the top left and linux does not load. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Dude you Data wont be on the disk if you boot linux. Your data is on a filesystem and linux got installed on a different filesystem that overwrote the current one. a filesystem is a type of agreement how a file should be stored what combination of ones and zeros indicate the beginning and the end of the file. bevor installing a so looking like "hacker distro" that gets previewed with he gnome desktop and 90% of the preview is the gnome desktop LOL. read something for yourself about how things work. yes I know reading sucks

Comment: and wikipedia eats time but thats the only way to understand the basics of the basics.
Try to ask yourself what every compenent of the computer does and why they are needed start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer#Components
and if you are far enough to start something with a different os: thats means you get the fact that the desktop is realy just a really small part of an operating system: Read foryouself what: Unix is, a kernel is, and then how to install Linux This guide is awesome!!! http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/

Comment: I will make sure to read this, I greatly appreciate your effort, I found a software and I was able to get there; http://image.prntscr.com/image/4e458a44f279470a90ccc6356b14fdd1.png I searched on some folders but most of it was empty, do you think that there's hope or did I lost my files forever?

Comment: What you see here are the folders of the Installed Linux distro. (similar to the WINDOWS folder on your disk) your files wont get shown because the file system where they are in doesn't recognize them. The installation formatted the disk. I really think you can get your files back by using a recovery tool that recovers files from formated disks. This one seems famous: http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/recover-formatted-partition.htm
If it wont do the job maybe this can help you http://superuser.com/questions/701335/recover-hard-drive-accidentally-reformatted-from-ntfs-to-ext4

Comment: And if this helped you, please do me a favour, and mark my answer as accepted. That means a lot to me. If you have any other questions left just ask! But try to Google before, at least once, okeay?